# Is it possible to map an object from more than one object as the source

Tags: automapper, orika

Lets say I get the following objects:
Street, City, State, Country, Continent. each has Id & Name fields.

Now, I want to create, using Orika automapping an address object that has the following fields
Address - StreetName, CityName, StateName, CountryName, ContinentName.

Can I do it not using a middle object?
What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a common entry point to this objects you can

```
classMap(Adress.class, Root.class)
.field("cityName", "city.name")
.field("countryName", "country.name")
```

if you don't have this root class, you can't